# Getting current position from media player is throwing illegal state exception

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

This is how I'm getting current position from media player but randomly it throws illegal state exception

```
override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        mp!!.start()
        timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                val intent = Intent(SONG_INTENT)
                intent.putExtra(SONG_KEY, PROGRESS_BROADCAST)
                intent.putExtra(CURRENT_PROGRESS, mp.currentPosition)
                intent.putExtra(MAX_PROGRESS, mp.duration)
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this@AudioPlayerService).sendBroadcast(intent)

            }
        }, 0, 1000)
    }
```

what could be possible error

Comment: So which state is the player in when the exception occurs? That should give you some idea of what might be wrong.

Comment: U can see media player is started... I've implemented onPreparelistener

Comment: We have no idea what you're doing with that `MediaPlayer` instance elsewhere in your code. If the player was in the correct state then it shouldn't be throwing that exception. So what is the state of the player when the exception occurs?